# how can I write my own push method WITHOUT using any array methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays

for this test, it should works, but i don't know what's wrong

i don't know why , but in webstorm it is working, but on course website no, i guess on website there is other return structure, and i should add this. somewhere, but i don't know where.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. thank you stack overflow, but i want to post my question

```
it(`Push method should work with many items

input: [1, 2, 3].push(72, 12, 41)`, () => {
    const source = [1, 2, 3];
    source.push2(72, 12, 41);

    expect(source)
      .toEqual([1, 2, 3, 72, 12, 41]);
});

source.push2 = function(...param){

  const parameters = [...param];
  for (const item of parameters) {
    source[source.length] = item;
  }

  return source;
};
```

Comment: Follow [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.push).

Comment: Can you explain what you would like to achieve?What is the purpose of this custom push function?

Comment: i need to implement my own push function which should take arguments and push it into array. WITHOUT using ANY array methods

Comment: Why do you say it's not working?

Comment: Check the docs, `push` returns the new length, not the array. By the way `const parameters = [...params]` is superfluous, you can just have `for (const item of params)`.

Comment: you need to use the prototype, insert the items on `this` at index, and then update the length.

Comment: [1,2,3,72,12,41] expected
[1,2,3]  received

Comment: You'll need to put the `source.push2` assignment inside the `it` function, after the `source` declaration

Comment: One could argue that this still uses the `Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You should use `this`

```
anotherArray.push2 = source.push2;
anotherArray.push2(1) // pushes 1 into *source*
```

2. You should use `Array.prototype`

```
anotherArray2.push2(1) // error: anotherArray2 doesn't have .push2
Array.prototype.push2 = source.push2
anotherArray2.push2(1) // ok
```

3. You should return `length`

```
console.log(['a','b','c'].push('d')) // 4 // builtin push returns 4 as expected
console.log(['a','b','c'].push2('d')) // ['a','b','c','d']
```

Comment: @PeterSeliger where so you see the usage of array methods? (other then `console.log` example that shows that implementation is incorrect. (The task is probably "do not reuse existing methods")

Comment: Please accept my apology. I haven't read carefully enough. So I failed on `push` versus `push2` where `push2` refers the OP's own implementation. If you (slightly) edit your answer, I'm able and happy to withdraw/reject my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

You mean something like below

```js
Array.prototype.push2 = function(...args) {
  for (const arg of args) {
    this[this.length] = arg;
  }
  return this.length;
};

const myArray = [1, 2, 3];

console.log({ myArray });
console.log(
  'myArray.push2(72, 12, 41);',
  myArray.push2(72, 12, 41),
);
console.log({ myArray });
```